# What is .mamba_trash and how to remove it?

Tags: mamba

after I remove a micromamba environment by

```
micromamba env remove -n <env-name>
```

I run

```
micromamba env list
```

It shows an "environment" called

```
<the removed env-name>.mamba_trash
```

What is it, how can I get rid of it? I didn't find any instructions in the [mamba documentation](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be removed with

```bash
micromamba clean --trash
```

From `micromamba clean --help`:

```
  --trash                     Remove *.mamba_trash files from all environments
```